# apt install error. Panic: Incorrect version for previously generated inversion list

Tags: apt

I have a rabbitmq-server set up that was having issues on ubuntu 16.04 so I was trying to reinstall that.

I faced this:

```
$ sudo apt remove rabbitmq-server
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_xenial_main_binary-armhf_Packages
```

after running a `sudo apt update` (I needed to run `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` first from some other stackoverflow answer) I got this error when removing rabbitmq-server

```
$ sudo apt remove rabbitmq-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-corba erlang-crypto erlang-diameter erlang-edoc erlang-eldap erlang-erl-docgen erlang-eunit erlang-ic erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-nox erlang-odbc erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-percept
  erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssh erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tools erlang-webtool erlang-xmerl libltdl7 libodbc1 libsctp1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rabbitmq-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 178 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,243 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

panic: Incorrect version for previously generated inversion list.

(Reading database ... 34410 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rabbitmq-server (3.5.7-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
panic: Incorrect version for previously generated inversion list.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 255
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
panic: Incorrect version for previously generated inversion list.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After this all apt commands were having issues but I can't figure out where the `panic: Incorrect version for previously generated inversion list.` error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was caused by a broken/misinstalled version of perl which is used by some apt pre/post install scripts causing the apt install/remove to fail

the perl script was where the panic: Incorrect version for previously generated inversion list. error was coming from

fixed by `sudo apt install perl`